plotly write to image not work on windows11
I try below code in ubuntu22.04, it works fine. but when I run the same in windows11 (python 3.12, plotly 5.20.0) it hang at the write image line.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#%%
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 1])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False),
        yaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False),
        title="Start Title",
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None])])]
    ),
    frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 4], y=[1, 4])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[3, 4], y=[3, 4])],
                     layout=go.Layout(title_text="End Title"))]
)

pngname = "demo.png"
print("save start")
fig.write_image(pngname,format="png",width=800,height=500)
print("save image done")



The save start printed then hang forever, C-c can not interrupt it either.

This is apparently an ongoing issue in Plotly that hasn't been fixed. This thread recommends downgrading Kaleido package, that is used for static image generation, to older version kaleido==0.1.0.post1.
